# Populating json objects from two separate lists

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following two lists:

```
 ['value1', 'value1', 'value1', 'value2', 'value2', 'value2', 'value3', 'value3', 'value3']
 ['value1_link1', 'value1_link2', 'value1_link3', 'value2_link1', 'value2_link2', 
 'value2_link3', 'value3_link1', 'value3_link2', 'value3_link3']
```

I am trying to populate json objects in the following manner:

```
   [
   {
      "timestamp":"string",
      "ext":"value1",
      "discoveredlinks":['value1_link1', 'value1_link2', 'value1_link3']
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"string",
      "ext":"value2",
      "discoveredlinks":['value2_link1', 'value2_link2', 'value2_link3']
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"string",
      "ext":"value3",
      "discoveredlinks":['value3_link1', 'value3_link2', 'value3_link3']
   }
   ]
```

Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you don't need the first list, as all the info is in the second list. I can't guarantee that my solution is the most optimised, but one way you can do it is as follows:

```py
import json
from collections import defaultdict

links = [
    "value1_link1",
    "value1_link2",
    "value1_link3",
    "value2_link1",
    "value2_link2",
    "value2_link3",
    "value3_link1",
    "value3_link2",
    "value3_link3",
]

temp_dict = defaultdict(list)

for link in links:
    ext = link.split("_")[0]
    temp_dict[ext].append(link)

output = json.dumps(
    [
        {"timestamp": "string", "ext": ext, "discoveredlinks": discovered_links}
        for ext, discovered_links in temp_dict.items()
    ]
)

print(output)
```

you can remove the the `json.dumps` if you'd rather have it as a `list` rather than a json `string`